# Visual Studio 2012 WCF service Reference.cs only has one class after adding a method to the service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a WCF service running in the 4.0 framework in VS2012.  I added a method to my service and suddenly the service reference wouldn't update properly in another project.  The Reference.cs file would only have one class in it instead of the multitude of other classes it normally has.  The update reference process says it completes, and it does not give any error message.

I found this in the event log, but it was not consistently there:

```
    WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/18956358
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/MyCompanyService/SystemService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/MyCompanyService/SystemService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: WebDev.WebServer40
 Process ID: 13212
```

ListData is not one of my services so it is almost like that is something built into WCF.

After trying quite a few things I figured out that if I removed one of the existing service methods, and added my new method it worked just fine.  So it seemed like I had hit a limit on how many methods you can have with a service.  I tried the suggestions posted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/38d09aca-acd3-4eb8-a5d3-803a68de92d9/) that involve changing maxNameTableCharCount on the service and devenv.config, but I still had the problem.

The way my code is setup I have one WCF service that is broken up into many files using partial classes and partial interfaces.  What is interesting is that when I remove methods from other partial classes that doesn't solve the problem.  I have to remove a method from the same file or partial class that I'm adding to.

Thankfully I found two methods that were no longer needed, but I'm going to run into this again pretty soon.  A lot of people say that there is no limit to the number of methods, and that maybe.  It could be just a limit on the size of the XML being sent across.  But that doesn't explain why I can remove methods in another partial class, and it doesn't have any effect.

So how can I get around this with WCF?  Are there other alternatives to having multiple services or just switching to Web API which I may do anyway?

Sample Code:

```
    public partial interface IMyCompanyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SubmissionReturn SubmitApplication(MyCompanyAuthentication auth, MyApplication application); 

...30 other methods defined just like this one...
}
    public partial class MyCompanyService : IMyCompanyService
{
    public SubmissionReturn SubmitApplication(MyCompanyAuthentication auth, ResellerApplication application)
    {
        authentication.Authenticate(auth);
        MyApplicationBLL bll = new MyApplicationBLL();
        return bll.SubmitApplication(application);
    }
}
```

Each service partial class has the following number of methods
Service File A: 31
Service File B: 76
Service File C: 52
Service File D: 19

Comment: ListData.svc is built in. Built into ***SharePoint***

Comment: Could SharePoint be causing a problem here?  It is SharePoint so naturally I would assume it would.

Comment: Well, it's _some_ kind of SP problem. Make sure the SP site is up, that you're authenticated, etc. Maybe try to access that URL from a browser.

Comment: One problem with that.  This isn't SharePoint.  I'm working with an DotNetNuke front end hitting a WCF Service.  Really DNN isn't even in the picture at this point.  I'm just trying to generate the service reference.  I'm wondering if some piece of SharePoint that is installed is causing me issues?

Comment: Focus on `/MyCompanyService/SystemService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`. Where should it be? Why isn't it there.